# How to center cell contents of a latex table with different text lengths?

Tags: tables, text

I am using the array package to center vertically the text (see code bellow). The problem is that the text in the first and second column are not align with the first column. how can i fix this?

```
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{table*}
\caption{caption goes here}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label    
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|M{1.5cm}|M{2cm}|M{7cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{2cm}|}
\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{text} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{text text text}\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}   
text & text text& text text text text & text text  & text text text\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
text & text & {text text text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text agricultural areas around text text text text} & text & text& text\\
\rule{0pt}{5ex}
text & text & {text text text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text agricultural areas around text text text text} & text & & text& text & text\\
\rule{0pt}{5ex}
text & text & {text text text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text agricultural areas around text text text text} & text & text\\
\rule{0pt}{5ex}
text & text & {text text text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text agricultural areas around text text text text} & text & text& text\\
\noalign{\smallskip}\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table*}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the purpose of `\noalign{\smallskip}` and of the `\rule` commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit are the `\rule` commands that serve no purpose. I also removed the `\noalign{\smallskip}` bits, whose only effect is to disconnect the rules.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\caption{caption goes here}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label    
\centering

\begin{tabular}{|M{1.5cm}|M{2cm}|M{7cm}|M{1.5cm}|M{2cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c}{text} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{text text text}\\
\hline
text & text text & text text text text & text text  & text text text\\
\hline
text & text & text text text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text agricultural areas around text text text text & text & text \\
text & text & text text text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text agricultural areas around text text text text & text & text \\
text & text & text text text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text agricultural areas around text text text text & text & text\\
text & text & text text text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text agricultural areas around text text text text & text & text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may like to see a different realization:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\caption{caption goes here}
\label{tab:1}       % Give a unique label    
\centering

\begin{tabular}{M{1.5cm}M{2cm}M{7cm}M{1.5cm}M{2cm}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{text} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{text text text}\\
\cmidrule(lr){1-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
text & text text & text text text text & text text  & text text text\\
\midrule
text & text & text text text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text agricultural areas around text text text text & text & text \\
\addlinespace
text & text & text text text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text agricultural areas around text text text text & text & text \\
\addlinespace
text & text & text text text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text agricultural areas around text text text text & text & text\\
\addlinespace
text & text & text text text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text agricultural areas around text text text text & text & text\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]